# Having problem with Mathjax library, library is not transforming input to nice expression

Tags: javascript, expression, mathjax

I have a problem with mathjax library not reading my input

First I have linked library to html like this:

`<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML' async></script>`

Then Im trying to write in html trough javascript like this:

citatel is numerator
menovatel is denominator
zlomok2 is id of div that Im writing in

`document.getElementById("zlomok2").innerHTML = "<p>$$F(s) = {{"+citatelX+"} \\over {"+menovatelX+"}}$$</p>";`

But my output in html looks like this:

$$F(s) = {{1s^0} \over {1s^4+6s^3+11s^2+6s^1}}$$
It is in good format but it is not transformed to expression I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Okay problem solved, when you are using innerHTML you need to tell mathjax that innerhtml was changed, I have just used this line after:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"MyEquation"]);
```